# Problem with Django app - ERROR - models - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=2)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have part of the application for getting location over Google geolocate APIs. I'm trying to execute this part of code:

```
try:
    if self.rssi_vector_data and not self.rssi_coords and settings.GOOGLE_LOCATION_API_KEY and not self.rssi_coords_failed:
    json_data = json.dumps(self.rssi_vector_data)

    response = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=APIKEY', data=json_data, timeout=2)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response_json = response.json()
        if response_json.get('location'):
            coords = response_json.get('location')
            self.rssi_coords = Point(coords.get('lng'), coords.get('lat'), srid=SRID_FORMAT)
            self.rssi_coords_failed = False
            self.save(update_fields=('rssi_coords', 'rssi_coords_failed'))
            return self.rssi_coords_failed
    else:
        self.rssi_coords_failed = True
        self.save(update_fields=('rssi_coords_failed'))

    return self.rssi_coords
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(str(e))
```

But I'm getting this error: ERROR - models - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=2)

I tried to write another script with fixed values:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=APIKEY"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

data = {
        "event_type": "rssi_vector",
        "timestamp": "2023-03-03T16:42:42+00:00",
        "payload": {
        "rssi_vector_data": {
            "considerIp": "false",
            "radioType": "lte",
            "cellTowers": [
            {
                "cellId": 0,
                "mobileCountryCode": 0,
                "mobileNetworkCode": 0,
                "signalStrength": 0
            }
            ],
            "wifiAccessPoints": [
            {
                "macAddress": "E0:23:FF:11:41:90",
                "signalStrength": -93,
                "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
            },
            {
                "macAddress": "E0:23:FF:11:41:91",
                "signalStrength": -94,
                "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
            }
            ]
        }
        }
    }
try:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data), timeout=2)
    response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print("Expired.")
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Error:", e)
else:
    response_data = response.json()
    print(response_data)
```

And it works.

Thank you for help!

I tried with several python versions and result is same. Just to note, timeout is not a problem.